# Nginx upstream timed out

Tags: nginx, tomcat7

Newbie to Nginx and Tomcat setup. Can someone help me understand what this error message means.

`2014/09/21 00:10:03 [error] 293#0: *127 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.211, server: my.server.com, request: "POST /path/dosomething.json HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.10.11:7070/path/dosomething.json";, host: "my.server.com"`

When debug mode is turned ON on nginx.

`2014/09/21 13:19:54 [error] 303#0: *37 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: --- same as above ---`

`7070` is `Tomcat`. I noticed this works for the first query after tomcat has been rebooted. But the next query after that gives the above error message. `nginx` and `Tomcat` are on same box.

Can someone walk me through, what this error message means and how can this be resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that after requesting `http://192.168.10.11:7070/path/dosomething.json` nginx hanged reading for [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) seconds on the socket used to communicate with your tomcat server and didn't receive any data. Investigate on tomcat's side to understand why it doesn't respond in time.

Comment: Thank for your response. I will look at the log statements from tomcat. But how come it worked the first time after tomcat rebooted and then it stopped working. It should fail consistently.

Comment: @java_dude Depends on your setup and what your application is doing. Maybe the first request caused full GCs, maybe your are connecting to a database not responding or overloaded, maybe your tomcat has not enough threads etc. It can have many reasons, but I don't have these details so I can only vaguely give these pointers.

Comment: Well thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. Appreciate your help. The problem was to do with connection using Apache HTTPClient.